# Exercise in RoR book by M. Hartl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been following the exercises in the [Ruby-on-Rails tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book) by M. Hartl. I have completed all the exercises in chapter 4 but am stuck on this one:

> Create three hashes called `person1`, `person2`, and `person3`, with first and last names under the keys `:first` and `:last`. Then create a `params` hash so that `params[:father]` is `person1`, `params[:mother]` is `person2`, and `params[:child]` is `person3`. Verify that, for example, `params[:father][:first]` has the right value.

Can anyone suggest how to approach this problem? I don't want to proceed to next chapter until I have solved this.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
person1 = {:first => 'Al',    :last => 'Bundy'}
person2 = {:first => 'Peggy', :last => 'Bundy'}
person3 = {:first => 'Kelly', :last => 'Bundy'}
params = {
 :father => person1,
 :mother => person2,
 :child  => person3
}
params[:father][:first] #=> 'Al'
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is another way to set up the params Hash.  I found it felt more familiar coming from a javascript background:

```
person1 = {first: "Papa", last: "Bear"}
person2 = {first: "Mama", last: "Bear"}
person3 = {first: "Baby", last: "Bear"}
params = {father: person1, mother: person2, child: person3}
```